# How to use a custom array type defined in WSDL?

Tags: c#, delphi, wsdl

Trying to learn how to consume a WSDL in a Delphi 7 application.
The WSDL I'm trying to consume has a custom array type.

**Pascal**

```
ArrayOfSomething = array of Something;
```

**How do I instantiate this array type?**

Have tried:

**Pascal**

```
var 
    somethingList : ArrayOfSomething;
begin
    somethingList := ArrayOfSomething...
end;
```

The ... above means I'm looking for a method and not finding one.  The normal way I would instantiate an object like:

**Pascal**

```
var 
    object : className;
begin
    object := className.Create;
end;
```

So you can see why I'd be trying to create the array in the same kind of way, even though it's not an object.

Bear in mind, I'm cribbing C# code and trying to make it work in Pascal.
The original C# is like:

**C#**

```
   List<Something> somethingList = new List<Something>();
```

And usage is like:

**C#**

```
   envelope.listField = somethingList.ToArray();
```

I've also tried this:

**Pascal**

```
   var
       somethingList : TList;
   begin
       somethingList := TList.Create;
   end;
```

Yeah, that works until I try to feed it into the envelope.

**Pascal**

```
   envelope.listField := somethingList;
```

Envelope is expecting ArrayOfSomething not TList.  Error is something like "Incompatible types, TList and ArrayOfSomething."

Answer (score 3):

An `array of` is a built-in type, it is not a class. To set its size, use `SetLength()`, e.g.

```
var
  Arr: ArrayOfSomething;
begin
  SetLength(Arr, 273);
```

Also note that it is not the same as a list, it is an array which has no built-in way to insert or delete values. You can read and change values, or change the size of the array, no more.

If you want generics, like in C#, you'll have to use a higher version of Delphi than 7. I'm not sure, but I think they were introduced in Delphi 2010 or Delphi XE. I guess someone can update me on this (Update: David Heffernan told me it's version 2009)

In these higher versions, you can also use TList<T>, which is probably what you want. Until then, you can use TList, which holds pointers (but is not directly usable in connection with WSDLs, so the contents may have to be moved to an array first). You may have to use New(), Dispose() and casts to use it.

Comment: Delphi 2009 for generics

Comment: Ok, so, to sum up, the route I'm going is just not going to work, but there is a workaround with TList.

Comment: @user You don't want anything to do with TList. You've got a dynamic array.

Comment: I don't know which route you want to go. Dynamic arrays can be very useful, probably also in your code, but they are not lists. To get lists like you are used to in C#, you'll have to get a more modern version than Delphi 7, which is, IIRC, about as old as C# 1.0 (which did not have generics either).

Comment: @Rudy the WSDL uses dynamic arrays. So suggesting TList seems to be a dead end.

Comment: @David: OK, then dynarrays are indeed the choice. I guess the OP will just have to get more acquainted with them (learn how to swim, in Delphi waters) before he jumps into the deep.

Comment: @David: He could of course use TList anyway, if he must insert and delete a lot, and then copy the contents to a suitably dimensioned dynarray. Or he could use a modern version and TList<T> and ToArray, just as he used to in C#.

Comment: He could do any of those things. But to use this WSDL he needs to use a dynamic array. All the talk of lists is a sideshow.

Answer (score 1):

```
type
  ArrayOfSomething = array of Something;
```

This is a Delphi dynamic array. You initialize it with a call to `SetLength`:

```
SetLength(somethingList, 42);
```

You should take a read of the [documentation for dynamic arrays](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types#Dynamic_Arrays) to learn more.